# Hide/unhide shapes in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have 3 shapes named oval 1, oval 2 and oval 3 and I need to hide/unhide that shapes according to a value calculated from "A1" where the resulted values are 10, 20 and 30 and when oval 1 = 10, oval 2 = 20 and oval 3 = 30. The image show an error box. How I do this?

```
Private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)

     If target.row = 1 and target.column = 1 then
          Me.shapes("Oval 1").Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value = 10)

     If target.row = 1 and target.column = 1 then
          Me.shapes("Oval 2").Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value = 20)

     If target.row = 1 and target.column = 1 then
          Me.shapes("Oval 3").Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value = 30)
End sub
```

Comment: The calculate event doesn't have a Target parameter - you need to use the method signature which gets created when you select the event from the drop-down on the top-right of the sheet code module: you cannot modify it to add a parameter.

Comment: @paolo - sorry, I had a comment explaining this on your previous question but deleted it.

Comment: Can I know what I need to change in my program for it to work?

Comment: I am a newbie in vba programming. I need to encode 3500 survey report so I explore myself to know that programming code to help me to lessen my work. So please me in my program. :)

Comment: People would be more likely to help you modify your code if you posted it in your question as text - no-one wants to type it out from your screenshot.  You can copy-paste into your post, ad use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Done editing my question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Private sub worksheet_calculate()
     Dim v 
     v = Me.Cells(1, 1).Value
     Me.shapes("Oval 1").Visible = (v = 10)
     Me.shapes("Oval 2").Visible = (v = 20)
     Me.shapes("Oval 3").Visible = (v = 30)
End sub
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, I still can't figure out how the other shapes get hidden.

Comment: If (for example) v is 20, then `(v=10)` will evaluate to `False`, so that gives you `Me.shapes("Oval 1").Visible = False`

Comment: Sometimes it is easy to overlook the basics.